# How to delete a created element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello I have a piece of code that allows me to add an author.
I have a problem, I can't seem to delete the created node in my table
This is the worst frustration in my life. I could not seem to delete it.
I also have notice that every time I inspected the element I could not see the
new created element from the source. But when I view it on firebug I can actually see it there.

Adding an input element and appending it on the table works fine for me.

I am just very new to JavaScript and to this web thingy and deleting a CREATED ELEMENT via .createElement is where I am stuck at.

here is my code

```
   <script>
   var ctr = 1;

   function showTextBox() 
   {
       // is the table row I wanted to add the element before
       var target  = document.getElementById('bef');

       var tblr = document.createElement('tr');
       var tbld1 = document.createElement('td');
       var tbld2 = document.createElement('td');

       var tblin = document.createElement('input');
       tblin.name = 'Author' + ctr;
       tblin.id = 'Author' + ctr;
       tblin.placeholder = 'add another author';

       tbld1.appendChild( document.createTextNode('Author' + ctr ) );

       tbld2.appendChild( tblin );
       tblr.appendChild( tbld1 );
       tblr.appendChild( tbld2 );

       target.parentNode.insertBefore( tblr , target );
       ctr++;
   }

   function hideTextBox() 
   {
      var name    = 'Author'+ctr;
      var pTarget = document.getElementById('tbhold');
      var cTarget = document.getElementById( name ); 
      alert( cTarget ); // this one return null? Why? I have created id="Author1"
                        // viewing this code on source make the created elem to not appear
   }                
   </script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I really need help. This is for my project at school.
Is there any way I could delete it. I created that node and I want it to be deleted when I click something.

Also I prefer to stay with JS not with JQuery or other JStuff and I am disregarding compatibility for now because this is just a sample in my dummy form. I will deal on that later.

EDIT
In case you need the actual form here it is

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process/" method="POST" />
    <h3>Book Upload</h3>

    <table border="2" id='tbhold'>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="book_title" name="book_title" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="book_author" name="book_author" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="bef">
      <td colspan="2">
        <a href="javascript:showTextBox()">add author</a> 
        <a href="javascript:hideTextBox()">remove</a>
      </td>                     
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to `alert(name)` in `hideTextBox()`. It should actually be "Author2" since you're increasing the counter at the end of the other function.

Comment: ^Great! I think it seems to work now, But I can see it on source. On the HTML Markup??? I am going to process this on a separate php form so can PHP still detect it anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function hideTextBox(){
    var name = "Author" + (ctr - 1);
    var pTarget = document.getElementById('tbhold');
    var cTarget = document.getElementById(name);
    var tr = cTarget.parentNode.parentNode;

    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    ctr = ctr - 1;
}
```

> Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D3kxT/)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I have done sorry for the late response. I have done it the same way as yours. Thank you very much!

Comment: This works! Getting the parent of the parent and then removing the child node does the job for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this function:

```
function removeElements(elements){
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
removeElements(document.querySelectorAll('#tbhold tr'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> every time I inspected the element I could not see the new created element from the source. But when I view it on firebug I can actually see it there.

If you change the DOM, you of course do not change the HTML source markup. Only the DOM inspector will show you the changes.

> ```
> var name    = 'Author'+ctr;
> var cTarget = document.getElementById( name );
> alert( cTarget ); // this one return null? Why? I have created id="Author1"
> ```

Yes, you created it using your `showTextBox` function. But that did also increment the `ctr` to `2`, so that you now are looking for `Author2` which obviously does not exist. So put a `ctr--;` before it and it should work.